# How do I convert kg·kg⁻¹ to ppbV (parts per billion volume)?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, ozone, gas, mathematics

I am using the CAMS model output data to figure out the ground level ozone at a particular place. It is given in mass mixing ratio, and I want to convert to parts per billion volume mixing ratio (volume/volume).

[image]

Shown above are ozone values from a model – basically the given values on the right beside the dates are in $\mathrm{kg} \cdot \mathrm{kg}^{-1}$. How can I convert them to ppbV?

Comment: For clarification: you are looking for "ppbV" (parts per billion with respect to volume) and not for "ppbM" (... with respect to mass)? Do you have some other parameters given? Is it a homework question? What did you do to find the answer on your own?

Comment: This is a VERY basic mathematical relationship unless I'm missing something, which I may be since you don't actually appear to ask a question in your question.

Comment: As @daniel.neumann wrote, we need some more specifics here in order to give a useful answer: do you simply want the parts per billion of **mass** (in which case it's trivial, as per Ash's current answer), or a molar fraction, or a volume fraction, or something else? I'm going to vote to close this question temporarily as "unclear what you're asking"; please edit it to add the necessary information, and I will vote to re-open.

Comment: @daniel.neumann Thank you for your response and my apologies for lacking clarity in my question! I am looking for ppbV. I shall explain what I'm trying to do. So I am using CAMS models' output data to figure out the ground level ozone at a particular place which is in mass mixing ratio and want to convert to volume mixing ratio/ volume itself.

Comment: @Pont Good Day Pont! Apologies for the question being ambiguous. Yes, I am looking at the scenario based on the volume aspect/volume fraction, in my case ppb, since I would be looking at the pollutant concentration rather than simply jot down the mass of the pollutant component.  Thanks!

Comment: @HalloweenKing Thanks for clarifying. I've edited your question to incorporate the information you provided in the comments. You can also edit your own question, should you want to amend my edits or add any further information.

Comment: @Pont Thank you for the assistance :) Will amend the question if necessary!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if you have a mass-mixing ratio, you effectively $\frac{ \text{kg pollutant}}{\text{kg dry air}}$. PPBV is parts per billion volume, or number of molecules of pollutant per billion molecules of dry air. Since not all particles weigh the same, you must use a conversion factor. Consider molar mass, which is the ratio of moles (a unit describing the number of molecules/photons/atoms) to mass. Ozone has a molar mass of 48 kg mol$^{-1}$. Dry air doesn't have a molar mass per se, but an effective molar mass may be computed by a weighted sum of the molar masses of the consitituent chemicals (or you can Google it). Afterwards, you may have to multiply by a billion.$$\therefore \frac{ \text{kg pollutant}}{\text{kg dry air}} \times\frac{\frac{\text{mols of pollutant}}{\text{kg of pollutant}}}{\frac{\text{mols of dry air}}{\text{kg of dry air}}}=\frac{\text{mols of pollutant}}{\text{mols of dry air}}$$

Comment: Thanks a ton Baroclini, this definitely answers my question precisely!

Answer (score 0):

1 part per billion is 1x10^-9 kilograms per kilogram so to convert a kilogram per kilogram ratio into a parts per billion figure divide it by 1x10^-9.

Comment: What's the source of this information?

Comment: @Imtherealsanic This is a very basic mathematical relationship, one most people should be able to manage in their head, what do you mean source?

Comment: I was going to ask you for a link to the article where you got the information provided in your answer, but instead I think I'll post an answer myself.

Comment: I posted a similar answer, but deleted it when I realized there's more than one way to measure a part per billion: the questioner might want a molar fraction, for example, in which case the calculation is slightly more complex. I've commented on the question to request more information.

Comment: The asker has now clarified that they want a volume rathen than mass fraction.

Answer (score 0):

@BarocliniCplusplus's answer is correct.
To convert Ozone (kg/kg) to (ppbv) you only need molar masses of dry air (28.9644 g/mol) and molar mass of Ozone (47.998 g/mol).

(Mass mixing ratio in ppb) = (28.9644 / 47.9982) * 1e9 * (Mass mixing ratio in kg/kg)

[Source: ECMWF webpage]
[1]: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=153391710